# Is every $\sigma$-algebra generated by a Borel function?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{F}$ a $\sigma$-algebra. Does there exist a topological space $U$ and a map $f:X \to U$ such that $f$ is ($\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{B}$)-measurable and $\sigma(f) = \mathcal{F}$? Here $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $U$.

Of course, this is trivial if every $\sigma$-algebra on a set is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra with respect to some topology on the set. But [this needn't be true](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87838/is-every-sigma-algebra-the-borel-algebra-of-a-topology). This is a weaker problem.

Comment: What is $\sigma(f)$? Is it the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the set of $f$-preimages of $U$-open sets? (Separately, does the counterexample given at MO obviously not yield a counterexample to this version too?)

Comment: To your first question, yes that's the right definition. With regard to the MO post, it's certainly possible that these problems are equivalent but I'm not seeing how. If the equivalence is clear to you, feel free to post an answer accordingly

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, $\sigma(f)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ generated by the topology $\{f^{-1}(A): A\mbox{ is $U$-open}\}$. Right?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes. It's just the standard definition of a sigma-algebra generated by a measurable function. Since we're taking $U$ to have the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, it suffices to take preimages of open sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\tau$ is a topology on a set $U$ and $f:X\rightarrow U$ is a function, then $$Op(f):=\{f^{-1}(A):A\in\tau\}$$ is a topology on $X$ (since preimages, unlike images, commute with intersections and unions). Since per the comments above $\sigma(f)$ is defined as the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ generated by $Op(f)$ this means that $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(f)$ for some $f$ only if $\mathcal{F}$ is generated by a topology on $X$. So this question does indeed reduce to the original question, which has a negative answer.

Comment: This works, thanks. It simply never occurred to me that you could generate a topology by taking preimages...

Comment: @AlohaSine This is a useful construction in topology: it yields the coarsest topology on the domain of a function making the function continuous with respect to a given topology on the codomain. It's called the topology *induced by* the function (and the fixed topology on the codomain), and can be generalized to a collection of functions and dualized to a notion of a topology *coinduced by* a function(s) and a fixed topology on the domain; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_topology).

Comment: Interestingly these dual notions apply to $\sigma$-algebras as well as topologies. That is, if $f:X \to Y$ is a map and we have a $\sigma$-algebra $F_1$ on $X$, then $\{U \subset Y : f^{-1}(U) \in F_1\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, and likewise if $g:X \to Y$ is a map and we have a $\sigma$-algebra $F_2$ on $Y$, then $\{g^{-1}(U):U \in F_2\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. I would not be surprised if they apply to other structures as well.

Is there a more general (categorical) interpretation of these notions?